# Unable to create passworded AAD app using beta Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As of a few days ago, I'm unable to create an app with a password using the Graph REST API. The endpoint returns a 400 error: `New password credentials must be generated with service actions`. The REST call is

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications

{
  "displayName": "appname",
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "base64/UTF16-encoded-name",
      "endDateTime": "2020-12-31T12:00:00Z",
      "secretText": "some-secret-text"
    }
  ]
}
```

This was using an app with delegated Directory.AccessAsUser.All, User.Read and openid permissions. I'm the admin of the tenant in question.

Is this intended? How can I get it working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, looks the API has been changed, there is a new MS Graph API to create the password - [application: addPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Note APIs under the `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.

[image]

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{object-id}/addPassword

{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "displayName": "Mypassword",
    "endDateTime": "2020-12-31T12:00:00Z"
  }
}
```

[image]